# Stormpath runtime error: com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.filter.StormpathFilter was found, but is missing another required class

Tags: java, servlets, jar, stormpath

I'm trying to run a java web application including Stormpath for user registration.

I've added the following libraries to the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`:

```
-javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
-stormpath-sdk-api-1.0.RC3.1.jar
-stormpath-sdk-servlet-1.0.RC3.1.jar
-stormpath-servlet-plugin-1.0.RC3.1.jar
```

However, at runtine (after deploy) I get the following error:

`Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [StormpathFilter]: com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.filter.StormpathFilter was found, but is missing another required class.`

Anybody that can help?
I'm a newbie in web developing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Maven to manage your dependencies since the jars that you have added depend on many other ones.

In case you still want to do it manually:

1.Check out the project from GitHub:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java.git
```

2. Build the project:

```
$ mvn clean install
```

3. Download all runtime dependencies:

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime
```

4. Enter the target/dependency directory of the module you will be using.
For example, with the Stormpath Java SDK, the default option is an Apache HTTP-client-based runtime:

```
$ cd extensions/httpclient/target/dependency
```

Here you will find a list of all the runtime dependencies necessary for the module.

Note that Stormpath and Shiro use the SLF4J logging API instead of commons-logging. Commons-logging is however in the runtime dependency list because HTTPClient needs it. Because of this conflict, you will probably want to excludecommons-logging.jar and include jcl-over-slf4j.jar (downloaded from maven central) instead, which is compatible with SLF4J logging and satisfies the needs of HTTPClient.